# Falha ao tentar deletar registro no banco de dados

Tags: php

Estou tentando deletar um registro do meu banco após deletar arquivo físico de uma determinada pasta, a deleção do arquivo físico ocorre como esperado mas a do banco falha, o que fiz foi isso:

```
if ($_POST["Operacao"] == 'ExcluirUpload') {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM gerDoctoContrato WHERE IdDocumento = ? AND IdContrato = ?";

if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql) ){
    $stmt->bind_param(
        "ii",
        $_POST["IdDocumento"],
        $_POST["IdContrato"]            
    ); 


    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $data = array();    
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $CaminhoAnexo = $row['CaminhoAnexo'];
            $NomeArquivo = $row['NomeArquivo'];     

            unlink($CaminhoAnexo.$NomeArquivo);

        }

        $sqlUp = "DELETE FROM gerDoctoContrato WHERE IdDocumento = ? AND IdContrato = ?";
        if($stmts = $conn->prepare($sqlUp) ){           
            $stmst->bind_param(
                "ii",
                $_POST["IdDocumento"],
                $_POST["IdContrato"]            
            );  
        }

        $aretorno["msg"] = "Registro exclu&iacute;do com sucesso.";
        $aretorno["par"] = $_POST["IdContrato"];

    } else {
        $aretorno["msg"] = "Ocorreu um erro na exclus&atilde;o dos dados: " . $stmt->error . ". Verifique.";
        $aretorno["status"] = "ERRO";
    }

} else {
    $aretorno["msg"] = "Ocorreu um erro na prepara&ccedil;&atilde;o dos dados: "  . $stmt->error . ". Verifique.";
    $aretorno["status"] = "ERRO";
}
```

}

No meu console aparece isso:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.unbind is not a function
```

Comment: que erro aparece?

Comment: Acostuma ser erro de integridade referencial, ou seja este documento esteja sendo ligado em outra tabela , o código dele esteja dentro de outra tabela. Verifica ai se é. Se for isto para resolver é preciso deletar tudo que tem relação ou seta null no local para possibilitar deleção.

Comment: `e.unbind is not a function` isso parace erro de javascript e não de php.

Comment: Fiz um teste comentado o trecho que deveria fazer a deleção e o script funciona, claro, não deletando o registro do BD.

Comment: Qual erro aparece? do jeito que está parece, que o evento do javascript falhou e não chama o arquivo php para deletar o registro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver, troquei o script de deleção por um que tenho funcionando em outro script e agora está deletando, no final, logo após anexar as variáveis com bind_param() os comandos `$stmts->execute();`   e `$stmts->close();` foram executados, ficando assim:

```
if ($_POST["Operacao"] == 'ExcluirUpload') {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM gerDoctoContrato WHERE IdDocumento = ? AND IdContrato = ?";

if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql) ){
    $stmt->bind_param(
        "ii",
        $_POST["IdDocumento"],
        $_POST["IdContrato"]            
    ); 


    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $data = array();    
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $CaminhoAnexo = $row['CaminhoAnexo'];
            $NomeArquivo = $row['NomeArquivo'];     

            unlink($CaminhoAnexo.$NomeArquivo);

        }

        $sqls = "DELETE FROM gerDoctoContrato WHERE IdDocumento = ? AND IdContrato = ?";
        $stmts = $conn->prepare($sqls);
        $stmts->bind_param(
        'ii', 
        $_POST['IdDocumento'],
        $_POST['IdContrato']);
        $stmts->execute(); 
        $stmts->close();

        $aretorno["msg"] = "Registro exclu&iacute;do com sucesso.";
        $aretorno["par"] = $_POST["IdContrato"];

    } else {
        $aretorno["msg"] = "Ocorreu um erro na exclus&atilde;o dos dados: " . $stmt->error . ". Verifique.";
        $aretorno["status"] = "ERRO";
    }

} else {
    $aretorno["msg"] = "Ocorreu um erro na prepara&ccedil;&atilde;o dos dados: "  . $stmt->error . ". Verifique.";
    $aretorno["status"] = "ERRO";
}
```

}

Comment: Qual é a principal diferente entre eles?